# Parse json from string Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, hdfs

I have Hive table with one column that contains JSON data as string.

How can I "convert" this JSON string into another table (that contains all JSON fields etc), What is the best way to do that? I want to insert row from JSON string into my table

Or there is another way to parse JSON into table?

I'm using Java-Spark.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use hive context to save dataframe in hive
spark 1.6

```
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("jsontest").setMaster("local[*]")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val json = """[
  {
    "tag_name": "A",
    "item_name": "B",
    "timestamp": "2018-07-09T16:59:17.8232306Z",
    "value": 10
  }
  ]"""

  val jsonRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(json))
  System.setProperty("hive.metastore.uris: ", "thrift://ip:9083");

  val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)

  val df = hiveContext.read.json(jsonRdd)
  df.show(false)


+---------+--------+----------------------------+-----+
|item_name|tag_name|timestamp                   |value|
+---------+--------+----------------------------+-----+
|B        |A       |2018-07-09T16:59:17.8232306Z|10   |
+---------+--------+----------------------------+-----+

//save into table
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).insertInto(tableName)
```

spark > 2.0

```
val spark = SparkSession .builder() .appName( "SparkSessionZipsExample" ) .config( "spark.sql.warehouse.dir" , warehouseLocation) .enableHiveSupport() .getOrCreate()
```